# Why do WPF Margins crop the control?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, visual-studio-2012

**Please see the update**

I have the following WPF controls.

```
<Grid>
    <Label Content="Report Generator" Margin="0,0,0,294"/>
    <TextBox Name="FilePath" Width="300" Height="25" Margin="10,30,207,264"/>
    <Button Width="75" Click="Browse" Margin="335,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Content="Browse" />
    <Button Width="75" Height="25" Click="Extract" Margin="432,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Extract" />
    <ProgressBar x:Name="ExtractBar" Margin="10,70,107,204"/>
    <Label x:Name="FirstEntityCount" Content="Number of Type1 Entities: " Margin="0,191,0,98" />
    <Label x:Name="SecondEntityCount" Content="Number of Type2 Entities: " Margin="0,226,0,65" />
</Grid>
```

I've quickly thrown this together in Visual Studio 2012 designer. The target Framework is .Net 4.5 and this is a WPF Window. It's an addition to an existing solution.

The issue is that if I don't remove the 3rd and 4th margins (e.g. Margin="a,b,c,d", setting c and d to 0) and then specifying `VerticalAlignment="Top"` and `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` the controls are cropped.

See attached image below.[image: Missing parts of controls]

I can rectify this by setting the margins to be 0 and setting the alignments but I want to know why this happens by default? I literally have just dragged and dropped. The controls appear normal in Visual Studio 2012.

Running Windows 8 RTM.

**UPDATE**

My question isn't why the margins now work and why the didn't before (I get that they seem to be set so they crop the actual control itself); I'm merely asking why this complex IDE fluffs it all up... It's happened over 2 rebuilds...
From what I remember, it also happens in Expression Blend. I'll double check.

Comment: If you want absolute positioning, use a `Canvas`. You're abusing margins here !

Comment: Do not use the VS designer. I don't think you will ever get any good XAML from it. Besides, it is just faster to type XAML yourself

Comment: @NicolasRepiquet I know I'm abusing them now, that's just how Visual Studio did them. I feel sorry for the poor things.

Comment: @HighCore I have a feeling that's what I'd have to do. It was just thrown together as a proof of concept for my little library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you drag and drop from the designer, whether it be in Visual Studio or Expression blend, the designer will attempt to place the element in the *exact* location the control was dropped on the designer surface. When the designer places the element, margins are used to position the control relative to the containing element.

What is typically done when dragging controls onto the design surface is to reset the margins. In Blend and VS, you can reset any attribute to their default settings by clicking the little square in the properties and selecting reset.

Agreed that the setting of the margins by the designer is a bit of an annoyance; though, not really sure of how else this would be handled when using a visual designer to drag and drop.

Personally, I tend to switch between hand written XAML and the designer; lately, I've been using Blend much more since it can control the placement of nearly any element in the XAML by using the objects and timeline panel.

On a side note, to clean up the Blend XAML madness, install the [XAML Styler](http://xamlstyler.codeplex.com/) extension for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

By setting the margins for top and for bottom, you are forcing the label to have a particular height. It happens that this height is not sufficient to display the height of the text that you have put in the label. I think if you reduce the bottom margin somewhat you'll find it fits OK.

On an unrelated note, wouldn't it be better to use Grid.Row and Grid.Column to position the controls on this Grid rather than having them all technically in position (0,0) and then using margins to position them?

Comment: Actually it looks like I misread the question - you're asking why the Visual Studio designer produces faulty layout. Can't help with that as I don't have VS2012 I'm afraid. Except to suggest that you either design your XAML by hand or use Expression Blend, because I've never found the inbuilt designer to be much good!

Comment: That was my question yes. I've elaborated on that further. Thanks.
I believe I'll either have to write it by hand or see if Expression Blend now works.